# ASP MVC Cookies not persisting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I have a ASP MVC App with some seemingly simple code to save and retrieve cookies but for some reason they won't persist. The code in the controller is :

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["CountryPreference"] == null)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("CountryPreference");
    cookie.Value = country;
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

And to load it again :

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CountryPreference"] != null)
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CountryPreference"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
    data.Country = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CountryPreference"].Value;
}
```

For some reason the cookie is always null?

Comment: Is the cookie there when you inspect the request & response with FireBug or something like that?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The problem lies in following code:

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["CountryPreference"] == null)
```

When you try to check existence of a cookie using Response object rather than Request, ASP.net automatically creates a cookie.

Check this detailed post here: http://chwe.at/blog/post/2009/01/26/Done28099t-use-ResponseCookiesstring-to-check-if-a-cookie-exists!.aspx

---

Quote from the article in case the link goes down again ....

> The short explanation, if you don’t
>   like to read the entire story
>
> If you use code like “if
>   (Response.Cookies[“mycookie”] != null)
>   { … }”, ASP.Net automatically
>   generates a new cookie with the name
>   “mycookie” in the background and
>   overwrites your old cookie! Always use
>   the Request.Cookies-Collection to read
>   cookies!

[ [More detail in the article](http://chwe.at/blog/post/2009/01/26/Done28099t-use-ResponseCookiesstring-to-check-if-a-cookie-exists!.aspx) ]

Comment: I +1'd this a long time ago but I have to say this was one of the most asinine API decisions ever done by Microsoft in .NET.

Comment: iv'e got the same problem and i only use request to read cookies 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510327/cookie-values-disappear-when-page-re-loads

Comment: I know better than to use request instead of response when CREATING a cookie, but for some reason when GETTING it I must of copied and pasted and left it as response - so my cookies weren't persisting past the first page load.  Thanks for this!

Comment: Hmm... could this behavior be used to intentionally delete an existing cookie?

Answer (score 2):

In resume, don't use "**Response**" to read cookies, use "**Request**".