# Cookie gets deleted right away

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I add acces token to users cookies, first time when I check if it is still there, it is. But next time I look for it, it isn't there. Does it get deleted when I get it from cookies? Or what I got wrong?

This is how I add cookie:

```
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(key);
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10);       
        HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on that but have you tried using `DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10)` instead of using the local timezone?

Comment: @KaiEichinger Yea, I looked on the cookie properties, and it said like 30 minutes from the time I looked. I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510327/cookie-values-disappear-when-traversing-between-content-pages, so I guess I won't be able to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing just a little mistake, to add cookies use **Response** rather than **Request**

**Corrected code:**

```
 HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(key);
 cookie.Value = value;
 cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10);
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Comment: and to get cookies? same collection?

Comment: Your method to get cookies is correct, the problem was only in adding cookies..:)

Answer (score 0):

> For security reasons, you can read only cookies that are set by pages
>   that are part of the same domain. If the cookie's Path property has
>   been set, that cookie is available only to pages and subfolders within
>   that path of the domain.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd70eh18%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

You might check that you're not trying to read the cookie from a different page than it was set.

Also see this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.cookies%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> ASP.NET includes two intrinsic cookie collections. The collection
>   accessed through the Cookies collection of HttpRequest contains
>   cookies transmitted by the client to the server in the Cookie header.
>   The collection accessed through the Cookies collection of HttpResponse
>   contains new cookies created on the server and transmitted to the
>   client in the Set-Cookie header.
>
> After you add a cookie by using the HttpResponse.Cookies collection,
>   the cookie is immediately available in the HttpRequest.Cookies
>   collection, even if the response has not been sent to the client.

You're setting the Cookie in the Request collection and then trying to read it back out. Perhaps you should try reading it from the Response.Cookies collection instead?

I.e. change

```
HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[key];
```

to

```
HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[key];
```